# Meaning of "**" in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

Can someone tell me what's the meaning of ** in Verilog.
For an example, what is result of 2**i, if i=3 is genvar in generate block?

Comment: Research effort in this question is null. A simple Google query or a quick read at any Verilog manual should have provided you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** in Verilog is an arithmetic operator: 2**i means 2 to the power of i.
When i=3, this equals 8.